# Attaching modules to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Form Events

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using Typescript to write custom code to handle form events.  For each form, I have a separate file and then I combine the files at compile time into one file that I then use across all forms.  I am having trouble attaching events to the form - I get an error that my function name can't be found.  Below is one of the requirejs modules that is in the compiled Javascript file.  I have tried connecting the events using `Evaluation.[function]`, `Forms/Evaluation.[function]`, and `EvaluationScripts.[function]` without any luck. What naming structure should I be using to attach my form events?

### tsc compile

```
define("Forms/Evaluation", ["require", "exports", "Global/Helpers", "Global/CCSEQ", "Global/Sync", "Global/Util", "Global/Query"], function (require, exports, Helpers, CCSEQ, Sync_4, Util_10, Query) {
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var EvaluationScripts = (function (_super) {
__extends(EvaluationScripts, _super);
function EvaluationScripts() {
var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
_this.EmployeeStaffLevelAsOfDateQuery = //query;
return _this;
}
EvaluationScripts.prototype.onLoad = function () {

};
EvaluationScripts.prototype.onSave = function (execObj) {

};
EvaluationScripts.prototype.ccseq_employeeid_onChange = function () {

};

return EvaluationScripts;
}(Helpers.FormLibrary));
exports.Evaluation = new EvaluationScripts();
});
```

### Update

I have tried to use Webpack to compile my modules as well, but I am still getting an error when I connect the `onLoad` function to the `onLoad` event.  Below is an example of my Webpack-compiled file.

### Webpack-Compile

```
var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, exports, __webpack_require__(6)], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function (require, exports, EvaluationForm) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Evaluation = EvaluationForm;
}.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__),
                __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));


/***/ }),
/* 6 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, exports, __webpack_require__(7), __webpack_require__(1), __webpack_require__(4), __webpack_require__(0), __webpack_require__(3)], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function (require, exports, Helpers, CCSEQ, Sync_1, Util_1, Query) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var evaluationPeriodDate;
    var EmployeeStaffLevelAsOfDateQuery = xml;
    function onLoad() {

    }
    exports.onLoad = onLoad;
    function onSave(execObj) {

    }
    exports.onSave = onSave;
    function onCreate() {

    }
    exports.onCreate = onCreate;
    function ccseq_employeeid_onChange() {

    }
    exports.ccseq_employeeid_onChange = ccseq_employeeid_onChange;

}.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__),
                __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up creating a new file that imported all of the Form files.  This, along with rexkenley's suggestion allowed me to connect the form events successfully using `CCSEQ.[FormName]`.

## Library.ts

```
import {Test as TestForm} from './path/to/form';

(<any>window).CCSEQ = {};

(<any>window).CCSEQ.Test = TestForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with webpack. The issue is the function is not being set to the global scope.

The simplest way to add the function globally is

window.Evaluation = new EvaluationScripts();

Comment: This doesn't quite work in Typescript.  I modified this to use `(<any>window).Evaluation = EvaluationForm`  in my Typescript in order to compile correctly.

Comment: I think the key issue here is that within CRM; any event handler function has to be globally available on the form.  Any way you cut it you will need the function called exposed in some global manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be slightly complicating thing trying to use WebPack.
I use TypeScript for all my CRM JavaScript and the pattern I use is to create a ts file for every entity that looks like:

```
/// <reference path="../type definations/xrm.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../type definations/jquery.d.ts" />

namespace xrm.entities.contact {

    class FormScripts {
        constructor() {
            //
        }

        private _onLoad() {

        }


        public OnLoad() {
            this._onLoad();
        }
    };

    //Expose the same js interface as the legacy code
    export var code;
    code = new FormScripts();
}
```

My OnLoad handler in CRM for the contact entity then looks like:

```
xrm.entities.contact.code.OnLoad
```

We use gulp to merge all the referenced libraries in to a single javascript file that can be uploaded to CRM as a single webresource

Comment: The goal is to not use namespaces and to use modules instead so this doesn't help a whole lot.  Gulp seems to be just as much overhead as Webpack to me.